# Why Client B didn't get complete file

Tags: java, swing, network-programming, thread-safety, swingworker

I am trying to build a file transfer mechanism between 2 Java socket client. The sender client would include this sorta snippet:

```
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    BufferedOutputStream outStream = null;
    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    int bytesRead = 0;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        bytesRead = bis.read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.length);
        outStream.write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.length);

    } catch (IOException _IOExc) {
        Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
            null, _IOExc);
        //QuitConnection(QUIT_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    }
```

The server mediator would look like:

```
public void run() {
    assert (outSocket != null);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[fileSize];
    try {
        System.out.println("inStream " + inStream.available());
        outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outSocket.getOutputStream());
        inStream.read(bytes, 0, fileSize);
        outStream.write(bytes, 0, fileSize);
        outStream.flush();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileTransport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
            null, ex);
    }
  }
```

the destination client:

```
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Start reading...");
            int len = 1024;
            BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream 
                  (client.user.getClientSocket().getInputStream());
            while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(fileBytes, 0, len)) > 
                  0 && current < fileSize) {
                current = current + bytesRead;
                System.out.println("current "+ current);
                bos.write(fileBytes, 0, bytesRead < len ? bytesRead : len);
            }
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReadFileThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
                null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
```

Both the server and destination client is passed "fileSize" in advance, the problem now is server side get slight less data and the clientB keep reading only 8192 bytes of data from server and can never get out the loop.

Many thanks
Kev

Comment: Try byte[] fileBytes = new byte[fis.availible()]; Maybe file.length() is returning a bad value. Why would you need to cast to an int anyway? Is file a File object? Or a String?

Comment: file.length usually return Long.... the read and send file is ok. I am just wondering the server side

Comment: Oh, so file is a File object? Did you try fis.availible()?

Comment: Not yet, but I don't think the precsion will go wrong by that casting. It looks like the clientB can't get whole data from server. Didnt' see the competing the inputStream at clientB thou

Comment: The painful thing is server side printing inStream.read(bytes, 0, fileSize) never return the same!!!

Answer (score 1):

Don't ignore the result of the `read()` method. It returns the number of bytes that have been read, which is not necessarily the length of the file. `read()` must always be called in a loop, until it returns -1.

And don't, ever, use `available()`. It doesn't return what you think it returns. Just loop until `read()` returns -1 or until the number of read bytes reaches the expected count.

Read [the IO tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html).

Comment: how about outputStream.flush(), should it be inside the loop after outputStream.write()?

Comment: You flush when you want to make the buffered stream send the contents of its buffer to its wrapped stream. Typically, when you don't have anything to write anymore to the stream.

Comment: Well.. the server side read() looks won't get -1, the total bytes aggregate differently every time. How could it happen when bytes sent ok at client A

Comment: Then read until you get the expected number of bytes. Just don't expect the bytes to be read in one call to `read()`. This is just how TCP and streams work. Even if you write 1MB in one call at client side, it could take 100 `read()` at server side to read them.